# @media rule behaving oddly in Chrome responsive design mode

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

Here is a simple HTML page that uses multiple @media rules:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .div1{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 500px) {
            .div1{
                background-color: green;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 499px) and (min-width: 300px) {
            .div1{
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 299px)  {
            .div1{
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page should change its colour as the window becomes smaller. It works as intended if I manually resize the web browser window. It also works under Firefox. However, it fails to work properly under Chrome's responsive design mode [Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Strangely enough, the CSS behaves as expected under Chrome's responsive design mode when I recreated it in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7g5jca8x/13/

What is the difference between the JSFiddle version and the HTML version? I can't figure this out.

Comment: Why adding a query for under 299px? there is no device under 320px ;)

Comment: @dippas it is just a test. Not the real code.

Comment: you are missing the meta tag viewport,

Comment: @dippas Can you please put your response as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution? It is strange that JSFiddle has meta viewport tag as part of its web design even though it does not scale to mobiles at all. I will need to find a more reliable fiddle for CSS stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the [viewport `meta tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) here is an example

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```